# Doctrine returns different responses array/object

Tags: php, doctrine

I have two Doctrine queries like so:

FetchBookRepository:

```
public function fetchBook($id)
{
    try {
        $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')
            ->find($id);
        var_dump($book);die();

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->em->close();
        throw new QueryException('003', 502);
    }

    return $book;
}
```

FetchAllBooksRepository:

```
public function allBooks()
{
    try {
        $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')
            ->findAll();

        var_dump($book);die();

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->em->close();
        throw new QueryException('003', 502);
    }

    return $book;
}
```

They both work as expected, but when i closely investigate the data returned I noticed that FetchBookRepository returns Object and FetchAllBooksRepository returns array of Objects.

[image: FetchBookRepository] 
[image: FetchAllBooksRepository]

Why is this happening what does the return depend on and is there a way to standardise the return...?

Comment: it's because when you use `findAll` you're asking it to deliver the objects of all the books in one single variable, so it puts everything in an array, while if you have only one result in your query it doesn't have to put it in an array first.

Comment: hmmm ok that makes sense, So I would have to wrap the array of objects with an object..?

Comment: No, you need to make a loop that goes through the array of objects, so you need two functions to process the results, the first one being just an object, and the second one could call the first function foreach object

Comment: OK I now understand it and as you suggested I loop through the array of objects and assign each object to a response which nicley outputs it. Thank you for suggestion.